# GRAILS-4.0.4 gives error like - No service found for type interface com.test1.MyDomainService -

Tags: grails, service

Creating a simple project with a domain as simple as possible and give the command "Generate all" and you get this error when you run the project.
Creating an exact copy of this project with 4.0.3 gives no error.

What is wrong here ??

Heres the dump:

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Lars\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.glassfish.jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.1\dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738\jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738/txw2-2.3.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738/stax-ex-1.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/dd6dda9da676a54c5b36ca2806ff95ee017d8738/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Lars\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.sun.xml.bind\jaxb-impl\2.3.1\a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38\jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38/txw2-2.3.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38/stax-ex-1.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar,file:/C:/Users/Lars/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.3.1/a1a12b85ba1435b4189e065f7dafcc3fb9410d38/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
2020-07-30 17:50:54.793 ERROR --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'runTestService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.ServiceNotFoundException: No service found for type interface com.test1.RunTestService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1771)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:841)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:99)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:485)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:472)
    at testing.Application.main(Application.groovy:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.ServiceNotFoundException: No service found for type interface com.test1.RunTestService
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.services.DefaultServiceRegistry.getService(DefaultServiceRegistry.groovy:81)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.getService(AbstractDatastore.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:123)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.DatastoreServiceMethodInvokingFactoryBean.invokeWithTargetException(DatastoreServiceMethodInvokingFactoryBean.groovy:30)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1830)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Comment: See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11590.

Comment: Ok, I'm satisfied with that. Think I stay with 4.0.3 then

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in Grails 4.0.4 and the solution seems to work perfectly by comment the first below dependency:

```
//developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
```